# YQL - Get youtube subscriber count for a user?

Tags: php, xml, json, yql

is there any way to do this with [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)?

Does Youtube even have a API that allows you retrieve such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an YouTube API right [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html)!

Comment: ok, i found out: `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USER` will display a xml with the info I'm looking for